# How to increate heap space for java in linux using .bash rc file

Tags: java, linux, bash, heap-memory

I am geting below exception while running my java code in linux server.
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Could you please tell me the way to overcome in linux server.

How to increase java heap space by using .bashrc file in linux server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added "java -Xmx16m class" in .bashrc file. It does not working.  It is throwing below exception whenever i restarted the linux server.   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx10g"
```

To be sure that it is working, whenever you run a java file, it should output: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx10g

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this has been answered before, but something like

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are saying that add this new line in .bashrc? Here JAVA_OPTS means new variale or existing one? or We need to create this environment variable?

Comment: As you suggest i added above line .bashrc file. But still i am getting the below eroor.                                        Message:GC overhead limit exceeded
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded